# Clean up after OpenCV installation

Tags: opencv, resource-cleanup

I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.3 library and followed [installation instructions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide). Installation went fine it was something like `cmake-gui` some configuration, then `make` and in the end `sudo make install`.

Everything went fine, but now I want ***to remove what can be removed*** and not interfere with the installation. There are:

i) downloaded .tar library -> this will be definitely removed

ii) extracted library -> I want to remove this but not sure if will interfere

***iii)*** folder with compiled libraries (release) .. this is the largest and I want to remove this :)

I was left with ***only 500MB+***. Before OpenCV installation I had ***3.2GB***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- .tar - it is ok to go
- extracted lib - You can delete it, but sometimes it's good to look in source of library, to get the idea why CV_ASSERT generated an exception and killed Your program
- release - You can delete it, because copies of everything inside are in Your system default dirs, like /usr/local/lib. Although to leave an easy way to make an uninstall, I'd recommend to check if `make clean` or `make clean-all` won't relieve You from Your insufficient disk space burden.